# When I browse localhost without internet connection my localhost server getting slow

Tags: xampp

I am facing a problem. when I browse my localhost without internet connection my Xampp localhost server is getting slow. I want to use this faster on my localhost without the internet connection. can you please give me the right solution?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the pages you are loading include references to non-local files (eg JavaScript hosted on Googles servers and/or tracking javascript) which can't be reached. To fix this, modify the HTML code to refer only to local /relative resources and mirror the required files.

Alternatively, if the pages still work, but slowly, remove the offending links or modify your hosts file to point the relevant documents to localhost [which could break Internet connectivity to them when you are online]